# Loading Javascript in webview

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I am really stuck in a condition where I need to load a Html and Javascript code in webview.
If is load it using an html file it works perfectly fine but not when I try to load it as a string.I need to load it as a string because I want to change the url in HTML dynamically.I think the problem is in the HTML string,can someone help me out.

```
  NSString *embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><HEAD><BODY>"
                           "<div id=\"fb-root\">sfd</div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=251520118193948\"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>""<fb:comments-count href=http://abcd.com></fb:comments-count>"
                           "<BR></BODY></HTML>"];


    [webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: it looks like you are missing a $ at the very beginning of your script block

Comment: I didnt get you,I donot think we need to put$ for JavaScript code??

Comment: What are the parenthesis for then?  It looked like you were trying to bind that function to document.ready with jquery

Comment: Yes and this is a working javascript code when I use it in a file.
I just need to figure out the way to load it as string.

Comment: So, you are trying to execute that function on document load?  I don't think that it is currently valid javascript.

Comment: Yes,so can you modify this js to work.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy:
please push in u boundle index.html with HEADALEX, BODYALEX inside html, and replace by u strings

```
NSURL *indexURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *index = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:indexURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

index = [index stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"HEADALEX" withString:htmlCodeHead];
index = [index stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"BODYALEX" withString:htmlCode];
[index writeToURL:indexURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) NSLog(@"PHONE CONFIG: write to file html error:%@",error);

[adsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: Thanks user170317,but i need to do it using string so that I can replace the string with the variable,because i donot know what is the string to replace,i just need to put that variable instead of hardcoded url.

Comment: htmlCodeHead and htmlCode is variable